# progress bar to download files after reading its size

Tags: python, download

Hello I am trying download some files online, I have written a small function that shows the size of the file to download, is there a way to show the progress bar of the download, I tried to use `tqdm` but it doesn't do it,here is the code:

```
from urllib.request import urlparse,urlopen
import os,shutil
from tqdm import tqdm

def read(url):
    response = urlopen(url)
    data = response.read()
    print("Read {0} bytes".format(len(data)))
    return response


url = "https://hls.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/v1.4/L30/2018/33/U/U/S/HLS.L30.T33UUS.2018005.v1.4.hdf"
file_name=os.path.basename(urlparse(url).path)
path="C:/nasa/"+file_name
with read(url) as response, open(path, 'wb') as out_file:
    tqdm(shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file))
```

also,is there a way to show how much time remains for the download to complete?